# image not appearing via css background property

Tags: html, css

I have an image not changing on hover and I can't figure out why.

```
<a href="#"><img src="images/image.png" alt="image" class="portImage2"></a>
```

This is displaying the image with no issues.
In my css I have

```
.portImage2:hover{
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/263/167);
}
```

and the image never changes on hover. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: you need to add css code for 'hover' event

Answer (score 1):

The background image and the image are not the same image.

When you change the background image, you just change what is *behind* the image.

If, and only if, the image is translucent you can see the change.

```css
.portImage2:hover{
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/263/167);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XNMmYECsALk/T37gk7mlWaI/AAAAAAAAATg/mM-XXtf5rZ0/s1600/bubble.png" width=236 height=167 alt="image" class="portImage2"></a>
```

If you want to change the image itself, then you need to change that (the **content**) and **not** the *background*.

```css
.portImage2:hover{
    content: url(http://placekitten.com/g/263/167);
}
```

```html
<a href="#"><img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-XNMmYECsALk/T37gk7mlWaI/AAAAAAAAATg/mM-XXtf5rZ0/s1600/bubble.png" width=236 height=167 alt="image" class="portImage2"></a>
```

Comment: Just read @Johny's answer and was agreeing we can't change the image of an `<img>` tag through CSS. Interestingly, I see we actually can!

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace image inserted as `IMG` tag with CSS background property. Browser won't allow you to do that.

Either set the initial background on `A` element and change it using `:hover` pseudoclass, or use javascript to attach onMouseOver event and update `src` attribute dynamically.

Both ways are still bot perfect (or my description is too simplified) but this problem is very basic and it is described in almost every tutorial/introduction to HTML & CSS.